# Designe view not working in Android studio in ver 1.5.1

Tags: android

If i make a new project using the Blank Activity template, the design view for the xml file will not work.
I get the following errors that are displayed in the designe window

**The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)**

Comment: Did you install the android SDK correctly?

Comment: file > invalidate caches / restart & clean/rebuild project.